# Why @Cacheable return different result on subsequent calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I am running Spring Boot version 2.6.14.

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/v1/books)
public GenericResponse<Book> getBooks(BookRequest request) {
  return new GenericResponse<>(
      loggedInBookService.findBooks(request)
  );
}
```

**Services**

```
@Cacheable("books")
public Page< Book> findBooks(BookRequest request) {
  return bookService(request);
}
```

**Request**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
public class BookRequest implements Serializable {

  private String isbn;

  private List<String> isbns;

  private LocalDate bookAddedDateFrom;

  private LocalDate bookAddedDateTo;

  private boolean hasCopy = true;
}
```

I received the correct response on the first request when setting 'hasCopy' to 'true' in the request. However, on subsequent requests, I received an incorrect response that behaves as if 'hasCopy' was set to 'false'.

What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, the immediate issue I see with your `@Cacheable` annotated `findBooks(:BookRequest)` service method is that your `BookRequest` object does not implement an `Object` `equals(:Object)` and `hashCode()` methods.

There are 2 things you need to know:

1. First, Spring Framework's [Cache Abstraction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache) uses the arguments to the declared parameters of your `@Cacheable` annotated method as the key for the cache entry by [default](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-default-key), unless you specify otherwise, either by using the `key` attribute or a custom `KeyGenerator`.

In your case, the cache entry for the `findBooks(..)` service method would be:

```
bookRequest: Page<Book>
```

2. Second, since a `Cache` is nothing more than a (glorified) `Map` data structure, then the `equals(:Object)` and `hashCode()` methods are important to implement.

I do not see that you actually implemented the `equals(:Object)` and `hashCode()` methods on your `BookRequest` object. Since you are using Lombok, you can implement `equals(:Object)` and `hashCode()` simply by declaring Lomboks' `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation on the `BookRequest` class.

However, it is important that the `equals(:Object)` and `hashCode()` methods consistently return the same value for logically same objects.

Given the fact that your `BookRequest` has an ISBN, and an ISBN uniquely identifies a `Book`, then rather than use the `BookRequest` as the "key" in the cache entry, you could instead use the ISBN by doing the following:

```java
@Service
class BookService {

  @Cacheable(name = "Books", key="#bookRequest.isbn")
  public Page<Book> findBooks(BookRequest bookRequest) {
  }
}
```

Again, see the ref doc on [custom keys](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key) as well as the [use of SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#cache-spel-context) in the `@Cacheable` annotation attributes, such as `key`, for more details.

If you do not have the [Java compiler debug mode](https://www.logicbig.com/how-to/java-command/compile-with-debug-info.html) enabled, then you will need to replace `#bookRequest.isbn` with `#a0.isbn`.

Using the `key` attribute on the `@Cacheable` annotation set to the `BookRequest` `isbn` should suffice, even without a `equals(:Object)` and `hashCode()` method implementation on your `BookRequest` class. But, this only works if the `ISBN` is always present in the request (and I suspect maybe not).

Also, it is always good practice to override and implement `Object` `equals(:Object)` and `hashCode()` methods, anyway.

Good luck!